# Displaying UITableView on a view and in popover changes the appearance

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I want to program a container which acts similar as a `UISplitviewController`. Here I want use the master view controller displayed in landscape and if the iPad is in portrait it should be hidden and a button in the navigation bar should be displayed. When the user clicks on the button a popover with the master view controller is displayed. So I'm reusing the same instance of the master view controller one time on the container view and one time in the popover.

When the rotation occurs the popover is automatically dismissed (because presented from `UIBarButtonItem`). Now the layout of the `UITableView` changes if it is in a popover similar to the layout described in the [transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/ContentViews.html). The background is a little bit different (despite it is white), the separator color is different and after rotation from the popover the unused table view cells have a **black background**. I tried to reload the table view in `viewWillAppear` but that didn't helped.

How can I redraw my complete table view?

Answer (score 0):

- If I set a background color on the table view the black table view
  cells are not there anymore. The separator color is different for the
  unused cells and the cells filled with data.
- If I set a separator color and reload the table in `viewDidLoad` I can manage this. But
  why is the default color here different? Another way would be to reduce the height of the popover so that the unused cells are not displayed.

But the question is why does this happen? The default values should be sufficient in my opinion because I set a default color in code which could change in the next release of iOS.